# Extracting between two words from Multiline textarea

Tags: javascript

On a create topic page I have a textarea which is filled in partially by code. Everything between the `confidential` tags is added by this code.

```
There is some text in the message!


[confidential]
{sitedetails}

Site URL: example.com
Site Username: test
Site Password: test

FTP URL: ftp.domain.com
FTP Username: test
FTP Password: test

Optional Information: Just some text for testing purposes!

{/sitedetails}
[/confidential]
```

On this same page this code runs:

```
var $editor = $(".markItUpEditor");
var curValue = $editor.val();
var sdCheck = curValue;
var sdAnalyze = /{sitedetails}([\S\s]*?){\/sitedetails}/gm
var newSD = sdCheck.replace(sdAnalyze,"{sitedetails}\n\n" + inputValues + "\n\n{/sitedetails}");
//alert(newSD);
$editor.val(newSD);
```

This basically replaces the site details with new site details. the `inputValues` are not visible here but they contain the site details and are working.

The above code could also easily be modified to remove the site details by changing this line:

```
var newSD = sdCheck.replace(sdAnalyze,"{sitedetails}\n\n" + inputValues + "\n\n{/sitedetails}");
```

to

```
var newSD = sdCheck.replace(sdAnalyze,"");
```

But how can I modify the code to keep everything that is between `{sitedetails}` and `{/sitedetails}`.

This should return:

```
Site URL: example.com
Site Username: test
Site Password: test

FTP URL: ftp.domain.com
FTP Username: test
FTP Password: test

Optional Information: Just some text for testing purposes!
```

And if possible how can I go even further and keep only between `Site URL:` and `Site Username:`

This should return:

```
example.com
```

Comment: out of curiosity, these are all key/value pairs. Why not just populate the textarea using a simple object rather than all the (very expensive) string parsing? Or, at a minimum consider string template literals.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am modifying an existing extension on our webpage without actually touching the core files. So I created a new tab to the create topic page with inputs. Now normally these inputs would be added via the extension but I don't though the core files so they have to be added into the textarea. And the first code I gave is how to update the textarea whenever new details are inputted.
Coming to what you say: `using a simple object` could I have an example? as I don't have an idea what you mean. Which is probably why I do string parsing.

Comment: It seems I don't understand your dilemma. You said: _Everything between the confidential tags is added by this code._ - if that is the case, within that code you have everything you need to accomplish your goals. But my experience is if one prefers RegEx they will go out of their way to ensure the solution is RegEx. I don't think I can add value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```js
var re = /{sitedetails}([\S\s]*?){\/sitedetails}/gm,
 urlRe = /Site URL:(.*)\n/
 
var str = $(".editor").val(), newStr = re.exec(str);
newStr = newStr ? newStr[1].trim() : "";
console.log(newStr)

if (newStr) {
  var url = newStr.match(urlRe);
  if (url) url = url[1].trim();
  console.log("URL:",url)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="editor" rows="10">There is some text in the message!


[confidential]
{sitedetails}

Site URL: example.com
Site Username: test
Site Password: test

FTP URL: ftp.domain.com
FTP Username: test
FTP Password: test

Optional Information: Just some text for testing purposes!

{/sitedetails}
[/confidential]</textarea>
```

Comment: Again you come to my rescue. Thanks so much for this code. It is however not entirely correct with this question. As a few things changed since earlier this day (for others reading this: mplungjan helped me earlier today with a great solution) but with a few modifications it works perfectly! Thank you so much again!

Comment: I updated to get the trimmed string between the tags

Comment: Updated to include the URL. I did not read the complete question before

Answer (score 2):

Well, for what I understand, and I may be wrong, you want to extract everything that is between Site URL: and Site Username: on the given string, and perhaps store it into a variable, then you can extract from a string this way:

```
sdCheck.split(/(Site URL:|Site Username:)/g)[Math.round((sdCheck.split(/(Site URL:|Site Username:)/g).length - 1) / 2)].trim();
```

This way you can get it. And what was done there is:

1. Split the string in an array with a regex. this way you will always get a odd length array.
2. Select the middle position of the array with Math.round and division.
3. A trim to remove whitespace.

This logic will only work if there is only one Site URL: and Site Username: match in the string, but it can be transformed for other scenarios.

Snippet:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea'); 

extract();

function extract() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text.split(/(Site URL:|Site Username:)/g)[Math.round((text.split(/(Site URL:|Site Username:)/g).length - 1) / 2)].trim();
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  extract();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" style="height: 200px; display: inline-block">
There is some text in the message!


[confidential]
{sitedetails}

Site URL: example.com
Site Username: test
Site Password: test

FTP URL: ftp.domain.com
FTP Username: test
FTP Password: test

Optional Information: Just some text for testing purposes!

{/sitedetails}
[/confidential]
</textarea>

<div id="result" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">

</div>
```

Comment: Could you show it implemented in the code I have? As I am not sure where to put your line.